# sendgrid username and password environment variables are not read when action mailer is executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, environment-variables, sendgrid

expected:

`telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587
EHLO
AUTH LOGIN
Enter username in Base64
Enter password in Base64`

`235 Authentication successful`

Actual:

Via localhost

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

config/environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  password:             ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

controller

```
NotificationMailer.notification_email(@admin_email, @item).deliver
```

sendgrid.env

```
export SENDGRID_USERNAME='apikey'
export SENDGRID_PASSWORD='the api key that was provided during the smtp setup'
```

now I do

```
source ./sendgrid.env
```

I check the ENV, it's shows the username/password.

```
rails c
NotificationMailer.notification_email(@admin_email, @item).deliver
```

I see the email gets logged, but I get

`Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed`

If I hardcode the env variables, the authentication does work. So I don't understand why the ENV variables are not getting into the process.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the dontenv-rails gem to solve this issue: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: You'd be correct if the question was about running in production, but that doesn't apply to the `rails c` console command described, which should inherit environment variables.

Comment: Will look into dotenv-rails today and update answer accordingly.

Comment: Improved my answer @inopinatus