# How to setup .envrc with proper importing of sendgrid.env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

History: [sendgrid username and password environment variables are not read when action mailer is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48139077/6430382)

Expected: email gets delivered to my gmail inbox

Actual: 550 error, because environment variables are not getting read when I execute the action mailer.

sendgrid.env

```
export SENDGRID_USERNAME=xyz
export SENDGRID_PASSWORD=zyx
```

config/environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  password:             ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

(If I hardcode the env variables, it works, but I want best practice)

.envrc

```
. sendgrid.env
```

.gitignore

```
sendgrid.env
```

Please advise

Comment: are you using ubuntu? is this problem about production on a cloud hosting or development on your local machine? did you save the environment variables in your `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: I'm using macos, development is on local machine, I can save the environment variables to my bashprofile (with source ./sendgrid.env).

Comment: still unix. I just save them in my bash_profile and make sure that your terminal is sourcing them .. you can do `echo ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"]` to test it in your terminal, then test also in your rails console.

Comment: I've used https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv that solves it for now